# What does Hawking mean by "in empty space the field can’t be fixed at 0 because then it’d have both a precise value and a precise rate of change of 0"

Tags: thermodynamics, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle, hawking-radiation

Slightly modified the language in the title to make it fit in 150 characters. The above comes up in the part leading up to the explanation of how black holes emit particles..

My impression was that the Heisenberg uncertainty principle is limited to measurements/observations (as opposed to what "is", regardless of our ability to measure it). While the point that the "empty" space outside a black hole is not truly empty seems to make sense, I don't understand the usage of the uncertainty principle to prove this point.

Answer (score 0):

The Heisenberg uncertainty principle does not relate to what *we can measure*, but rather what could be measured *in principle*. So if the field was fixed at 0, a precise measurement of the field and its derivative would always yield 0, violating the principle.

Comment: Thanks. Also read about the uncertainty principle not being the same as the observer effect, which pretty much kills the question.